# Where's the other verb in "Darf ich bei euch mal auf Toilette?"?

Tags: modal-verb

I wonder if this sentence is incomplete.

> Darf ich bei euch mal auf Toilette?
>
> Can (“to have permission”) I use your bathroom? (in a restaurant or
> bar)

Source: https://yourdailygerman.com/meaning-duerfen-german/

I thought it requires a verb that describes an action for "ich ... auf Toilette". For example:

> Darf ich bei euch mal auf Toilette gehen?

Comment: Nun "... in die Toilette urinieren" oder "in die Toilette abkoten" wäre besser, insofern als ein konkretes Verb benutzt wird, aber diese Vorgänge sind derart tabu, dass "Darf ich mal …" gefolgt von vagen Gesten die die verschlugenen Pfade zum Ort der Erleichterung andeuten angeraten zu sein scheinen.

Answer (score 9):

It is a general fact about modal verbs in German that they can appear without a full verb when the meaning is a directed movement:

- Ich muss noch in die Stadt. (I must (go) to town)
- Wir wollen weg von fossilen Energien. (lit. we want (to move) away from fossile fuels, i.e. get rid of)
- Das Kind sollte ins Bett. (the child should (go) to bed)

etc., including your example "darf ich auf die..."

It's entirely regular, and so in a sense does not count as "incomplete" (it is not considered an elliptical structure). Unfortunately, my Duden grammar does not seem to mention the phenomenon (at least I couldn't find it with the search words Modalverb or Direktional), and the German wikipedia mentions it but does not cite any source (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modalverb#Besonderheiten_in_der_Syntax_der_deutschen_Modalverben)

PS: I find a distinct, second meaning in which it's not a movement verb but a verb of putting that is understood:

- Das muss in den Kühlschrank. (must be put into the fridge)
- Das kann in den Müll. (can be thrown in the bin; note you'd hardly get "das kann in den Müll gehen" in G.)
- Das Kind sollte ins Bett. (second reading: ...should be put to sleep)

Comment: Is this more like a spoken convention? A short-cut in speech?

Comment: That's a point that I would have liked to look up :) It is not the kind of clipped phrase typical of spoken language. In my judgement, it is moderately casual, but you can use it in written language. As I said, it does not feel like an incomplete sentence.

Comment: With regard to the Duden grammar (8th/9th edition), paragraph 815 fits; the 10th edition doesn't seem to have anything.

Comment: Here https://storylearning.com/learn/german/german-tips/german-modal-verbs it says: "It's common in spoken German to leave out the main verb and imply its meaning.".

Comment: I also think it makes sense for very common phrases. They just got tired of having to be specific about the main verb.

Comment: Note the **die** in *darf ich auf die*. Just "auf Toilette" is used for sure but sounds very odd in my ears.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is covered in the DWDS entry for "dürfen", def 1.a.α under the section "[ohne folgenden Infinitiv]". I assume other modal verbs have similar sections. The note basically says that you have to figure out what the verb is from context. "Können" is especially notorious for this kind of thing.

Comment: @mavavilj I would say that yes, it is a shortcut in speech. Certainly, if elementary school age children talk like that, it is common for teachers to correct them.

Answer (score -2):

> Darf ich bei euch mal auf Toilette?

*Dürfen* ist das Hauptverb. Darauf hindeutet *Notdurft*. Außerdem könnte dem Ablautverhältnis mit *darben* eine ähnliche Motivation zugrunde liegen wie zu *sechen* und *siechen*; völlig unklar.

> Darf ich mal bei euch auf Toilette gehen?

*Gehen* ist atelisch, *darf ich mal kurz verschwinden* (wohin ist egal), bzw. telisch (auf die Toilette).

Das ist durchaus üblich. Allerdings sagt man ja auch nicht, *? aufs Sofa, ? auf den Stuhl, ? auf die Küche gehen*. Es handelt sich also um ein Idiom. Ebenso kennt englisch ein Idiom in gleicher Bedeutung: *to go (potty)*.

Wegen Beispielen wie *auf die Nerven gehen* ist das eher abstrakt zu verstehen. Übrigens deutet *Stuhlgang* ähnlich Abstrakt doch auch ein *? auf den Stuhl gehen* an. Wieder was gelernt.

Wegen *zur Schule gehen* ist *zur Toilette* sicherlich die feinere Ausdrucksweise; mag sein.

Atelisch *auf* spricht für Verwechslung mit *ab-*, *abtreten, abgehen* usw.; eher abwegig der Gedanke.

> Darf ich bei euch mal auf Klo [,] pipi gehen?

> Darf ich bei euch mal aufs Scheißhaus gehen: eine Stange aus dem Rücken drücken?

Weiß ich nicht Digga. Nach erstens und zweitens müsste da ein Satzzeichen stehen. Vong Sprachgefühl her bin ich mir nicht sicher, weil die Ausdrucksweise doch eher selten ist. *Too much info!*

Scheint mir aber doch der syntaktisch richtige Ansatz zu sein. *Gehen* ist telisch, *sich erleichtern* ist das Ziel, vgl. *schwimmen gehen*, *zum Schwimmen gehen*.